# Element 'block', attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 745

Tags: database, attributes, blocks, xml, magento-2.2.5

I'm getting this error when I hit the front end. Couldn't able to find any solution regarding this.

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'block',
>   attribute 'remove': The attribute 'remove' is not allowed. Line: 745

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: I thought you have try remove attribute in block....if you want to remove any existing block you have to use referenceBlock instead of block @anil

Answer (score 3):

in Magento 2, we can remove a block with the layout instruction below (it is an example)

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info" remove="true" />
```

now, reading your error, I suspect you have a line like this instead:

```
<block name="product.info" remove="true" />
```

I would look for the string remove="true" in your `app/design/frontend` folder and `app/code` folder